# Cannot access windows7 hosted network from lumia 630

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have created a hosted network in my windows7 system. But my Lumia 630 but my phone can't connect to this except once(when I started the hosted network first time). Every time when i try to connect I get this message:
"The WiFi network ONE1 didn't respond. Try again later"
But it does prompts me to enter the correct password when a try with a wrong password. The netsh wlan show hostednetwork command gives the output.

```
Hosted network settings
-----------------------
Mode                   : Allowed
SSID name              : "ONE1"
Max number of clients  : 20
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP

Hosted network status
---------------------
Status                 : Started
BSSID                  : 00:26:c6:09:d6:c3
Radio type             : 802.11g
Channel                : 11
Number of clients      : 0
```

I have Intel® PROSet/Wireless Tools installed in my system.I have tried all the methods I found in internet including changing ip adress, changing startup of ICS and routing etc. but none of them worked for me. Please Help me...

Answer (score 0):

First you have to run CMD.exe as an administrator:

1. Goto c:\windows\system32
2. Right Click on "CMD.exe" and run as administrator.
3. Now enter-> `Netsh wlan show hostednetwork`
4. `Netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=WIFI key=12345678`
5. `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`
6. when you want to close your wifi simply write `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork`

or you can also just copy these three line in notepad and "save as" a .bat file, and run that file as administrator.

Comment: I've have already done this and my hostednetwork is succesfully started. But the problem is my windows phone will not get connected to the wifi network. Every time i get the message
"The WiFi network ONE1 didn't respond. Try again later"
I even tried with an android phone but it kept on showing "authenticating"..

Comment: "The WiFi network ONE1 didn't respond. Try again later"

Comment: I even tried with an android phone but even it didn't work..

Comment: ok, You can do one thing, 1.goto control panel 2.Network and sharing center 3.click on your active network connections, then popup window will open 4.click on "Properties".5. choose sharing tab 6.Enable "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection. 7.select your network resources and then ok.

Comment: i think my problem is solve. I just disabled "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection" from sharing tab before executing the netsh code on cmd. After running the netsh code in cmd then i tried enabling the sharing and it started working. Earlier even before running the netsh code I've enabled the internet sharing option. I think the order of this steps matters